# Calling function in linked JavaScript file on click - Leaflet Maps

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html

I have a simple button which upon click will display a simple message

HTML code is as follows

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Javascript test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-hoalWLoI8r4UszCkZ5kL8vayOGVae1oxXe/2A4AO6J9+580uKHDO3JdHb7NzwwzK5xr/Fs0W40kiNHxM9vyTtQ=="
          crossorigin=""/>
    <style media="screen">
        main
        {
          display:flex;
        }

        .address-list
        {
          width:20vw;
          height:100vh;
          /* overflow: auto;
          background: #f5f5f5;
          padding: 0 1rem; */
        }
        #map
        {
          width: 80vw;
          height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <main>
        <div class="address-list">
             <input type = "button" onclick = "myfunction()" value = "Display">
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </main>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-BB3hKbKWOc9Ez/TAwyWxNXeoV9c1v6FIeYiBieIWkpLjauysF18NzgR1MBNBXf8/KABdlkX68nAhlwcDFLGPCQ=="
            crossorigin="">
    </script>

    <!-- <script>
      function myfunction()
      {
          alert("user clicked on Display button");
      }
     </script> -->
    <script type="module" src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code as follows

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([59.91200869359693, 10.742568969726562], 13);
        
  L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(map);
        
        
        
   function myfunction()
   {
       alert("user clicked on Display button");
   }
```

When I have the function is HTML file itself it works fine but when I move the function to JS file it gives me error message as `"Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined"`. When I do the same in a project with no Leaflet JS involved the script runs as expected (both from HTML and external linked JS file). Is there a different way of calling a function when working with Leaflet? Everything else from JS file is executed fine the issue is when calling a function on user input.

Comment: Please edit your question and add all relevant code of how you use your function with Leaflet.

Comment: @TomazicM I update the code now as suggested

Comment: Any errors in the browse debugger console?

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined"

Comment: You just have to leave out `type="module"` attribute from your script link statement, so it should be: `<script src="./script.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following suggestion from @TomazicM worked for me

You just have to leave out `type="module"` attribute from your script link statement, so it should be: `<script src="./script.js"></script>`